# sliding a shape with area= 5 on a grid so it covers at least 6 of it's points - riddle

Tags: geometry, puzzle

place a shape on an integer coordinates grid, which is continuous without holes, and that its area is 5. Explain why you can slide it (without twisting or warping it), so that it will cover at least six points of the grid?

Comment: Is rigid rotation allowed, or only nonrotational translation?

Comment: Do you have a precise definition of what "continuous without holes" means? "Open and simply connected" doesn't seem to work -- an open $1\times 5$ rectangle cannot be translated to cover six lattice points.

Comment: I think any compact shape will do.

Comment: If only translation is allowed, then the area of the shape should be greater than 5 or there are other restrictions on the shape. Otherwise, the statement can fail (e.g. 1x5 "open" rectangle ). If the area is greater than 5, then one can use [Blichfeldt's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlichfeldtsTheorem.html) directly.

Comment: @achille: Yes, that's why I said "compact". But the shape doesn't have to be connected.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A$ be any compact set with area 5. Fix a point $P$ in $A$, and define the function $f:[0,1]\times[0,1] \to \mathbb Z_{\ge0}$ by

$(x,y) \mapsto$ the number of lattice points covered by $A$ when $P$ is translated to $(x,y)$

Then the integral of $f$ over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is 5. So unless $f = 5$ almost everywhere, $f(x,y)$ must be $\ge$ 6 for some $(x_0,y_0)$.

Now, suppose that $f(x,y) < 5$ for some $(x,y)$. $A$ is compact, so its complement is open. Thus, when $P$ is at $(x,y)$, all lattice points that lie outside $A$ are bounded away from $A$. Hence there is a neighbourhood of $(x,y)$, with positive area, in which $f$ remains less than 5. (This uses the fact that $A$ is bounded, so only a finite number of lattice points can be close to $A$.) Therefore $f$ is not equal to 5 almost everywhere.

So now all we have to show is that $f$ can't be equal to 5 everywhere. Suppose otherwise, and imagine sliding $P$ from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$. At every point there are exactly 5 lattice points covered by $A$. But the set of lattice points covered when $P=(0,0)$ is not the same as the set of lattice points covered when $P=(1,0)$. So at some point $P=(a,0)$, a lattice point $L_1$ must get left behind by $A$ as it moves to the right. To compensate, a new lattice $L_2$ point must be consumed by $A$. But then at $P=(a,0)$, both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are in $A$, and we have $f(a,0) \ge 6$. QED

*Note:* It may be that more than one lattice point leaves $A$ at $P=(a,0)$. But then the same number of lattice points must be consumed by $A$, and the same argument applies.

Comment: (+1) Cool, I like the part you proved $f < 5$ at a point implies $f < 5$ over a neighbourhood with positive area.

Answer (score -1):

Start with a shape that is 100 x 1/20 rectangle, and stick it on the x coordinate line. That covers 100 points

Comment: OP is asking to show that any shape of area 5 can cover 6 lattice points.  Certainly some shapes cover many more, as you have shown.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is an example of what the question is asking, but that is not a proof.